# Create a data extension from a Synchronized Contact Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, sql

I am trying to create a copy of a Synchronized Contact Data Extension (from Salesforce) into the non Synchronized Data extension using a SQL query activity.

Can someone give me an example of the query I would use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the use case would help for long term viability of the solution. But, assuming that you're going to make a one time copy of the original DE (or copy and overwrite in the future), and also assuming that all of your field names are *exactly* the same...

Create a SQL Query:

```
select * from DE1
```

Within the SQL settings, select the new data extension as the target, and choose to overwrite.

If you have re-labeled any fields in the new data extension, then you'll have to update the query to something like:

```
select Id, FirstName, email as 'email address', LastName from DE1
```

Note that, in the example above, 'email' is the field label in DE1 while 'email address' is the corresponding field label in DE2.

Life is made easier by keeping the field labels the same.

Comment: Just a note that `select *` type query is not ideal when you make changes in the field names in the source DE. So I would recommend to go with second option suggested from the very beginning.